# Visual C++ conditional debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I am trying to setup a project with conditional debugging. What i want is to have a macro `debug` which is #defined to some kind of printf/cout/anything when I'm running in debug mode and #defined to null statement when running in production mode. How can I do this:

I have tried using the macro `_DEBUG` but I always see my arguments printing regardless of which mode I am running in:

```
struct debugger{template<typename T> debugger& operator ,(const T& v){std::cerr<<v<<" ";return *this;}}dbg;
#if _DEBUG
    #define debug(...) {dbg,__VA_ARGS__;std::cerr<<std::endl;}
#else
    #define debug(...) // Just strip off all debug tokens
#endif
```

In my main:

```
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a=1,b=2,c=3;
    debug(a,b,c);
    cin>>a;
}
```

If it helps, I am using Visual studio 2012

Comment: How did you try `_DEBUG`? You could also try `OutputDebugString`.

Comment: `#if defined _DEBUG`? or the standard `#ifndef NDEBUG`

Comment: btw, `_DEBUG` determines the CRT you are linking with, not whether the compilation is debug or not. Use NDEBUG and define it properly.

Comment: Are you sure you're setting your configuration to **Release** when building your Release build?

Comment: @ybungalobill That's completely incorrect. _DEBUG *does* indicate whether the configuration is Debug or Release. I don't think NDEBUG is used by VC++ at all.

Comment: @user1610015 : then why doesn't it work?

Comment: @chris : already done. doesn't work

Comment: @user1610015 : how do i make sure of that?

Comment: @prongs Right-click the solution name in Solution Explorer. In the left frame, select **Configuration Properties**. Then, at the top of the window there's a **Configuration** setting. Set it to **Release**.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18432/discussion-between-prongs-and-user1610015)

Comment: nope. still not fixed.
<f5> and <ctrl-f5> both give same output

Comment: @user1610015: [MSDN>_DEBUG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)... Hehe... I invite you to compile in debug mode with CRT set to, e.g. "Multithreaded DLL (`/MD`)" (non debug), and see that _DEBUG will not be defined. That's right tha NDEBUG is not defined by default, exactly because from compiler's point of view there is no discrete difference between debug compilation and non debug. It's your responsibility to define it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your samples is correct. The problem is where the definition `_DEBUG` is coming from. In the right setup it should come/not come from your MSVC project and from nowhere else.  In this case depending on the build type you will have what you are expecting.

Most likely you have it defined somewhere in your own code or in one of the header that you include.

There is no enough info in your post to infere the true origin of `_DEBUG`.

In debug mode the definition coming from MSVC will look like:

```
#define _DEBUG
```

This means that even in DEBUG build you should not see anything. Once you see the output, this means that the defn is present and it is not empty. This defn is coming not from MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
struct debugger{template<typename T> debugger& operator ,(const T& v){std::cerr<<v<<" ";return *this;}}dbg;
#if _DEBUG
    #define debug(...) {dbg,__VA_ARGS__;std::cerr<<std::endl;}
#else
    #define debug
#endif
```